# C# get value from Array in Deserialized JSON Object

Tags: c#, json, foreach

I've got a `JsonObject` that I deserialize to use the data that I got from an api.
Somehow I can't seem to figure out how I can get data from the array that I get back, though I can read what the boolean "ok" returns.
I tried to put the array in a foreach loop to retrieve all the names, but without success, because I don'

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "establishments": [
        {
            "id": "d2sd2-axsd7gjd2-g3sdasd",
            "name": "Hops n Beers",
            "address": ":HopeStreet",
            "lat": : 54.595112,
            "lng": : -5.935926,
        },
                {
            "id": "z1ty4-axst7jjd2-g3spocd",
            "name": "Good ol Bakery",
            "address": ":Bakerstreet",
            "lat": : 54.54312,
            "lng": : -5.11926,
        },
    ]
}
```

^ This is what the api returns

My goal right now is to get the name of the establishment through a foreach loop.
My code(removed the loop, became messy after trying all sorts of things):

```
var deserializedLocList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, object>>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
if ((bool)deserializedLocList["ok"])
{
    //I do get a true back, but here I want to create a foreach loop to get all the names
    await DisplayAlert("Succes", "HOORAY!", "OK");
}
else
{
    await DisplayAlert("Fout", (string)deserializedLocList["reason"], "OK");
}
```

I also created a class that I used while trying some things like instead of using the Dictionary creating a List.

The Class:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class LocationListResults
{
    [JsonProperty("establishments")]
    public Establishment Establishments { get; set; }
}
public class Establishment
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("address")]
    public string  Address{ get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("lat")]
    public string Lat{ get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("lng")]
    public string Lng { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you create a class that represents the structure of your data and then serialize into that type?

Comment: I did find something about doing that and creating a List, but I probably did something wrong. Will add the class that I created to the question, because I still have that file.

Comment: You can even use https://jsonutils.com/ to get a good starting point, after you remove the errors in the JSON.

Comment: Yes I was going to say the same as Dirk, go to the site paste your json to let the tool generate the class for you and the use it to load the json to an instance of the class or an array using the class it depends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best optimal solution would be to create a Class, representing the object that you are receiving, and deserialize the content into that type.

You're nearly there with that class, you've just have to say it's Establishment is a list of Establishments

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class LocationListResults
{
    [JsonProperty("ok")]
    public Boolean OK { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("establishments")]
    public List<Establishment> Establishments { get; set; }
}
public class Establishment
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("address")]
    public string  Address{ get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("lat")]
    public string Lat{ get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("lng")]
    public string Lng { get; set; }
}


var deserializedLocList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LocationListResults>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
if (/* access here the boolean 'okay' from deserializedLocList or whatever you require */)
{
    //I do get a true back, but here I want to create a foreach loop to get all the names
    await DisplayAlert("Succes", "HOORAY!", "OK");
}
else
{
    await DisplayAlert("Fout", /* access here the value from deserializedLocList or whatever you need */, "OK");
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Now I can easily acces everything through a froeach loop (: